# linux mint 16 kde cursor issue

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kde

I installed Linux Mint 16 KDE on my system today.
For some reason, when I move the cursor to the right, it goes away out of screen and I have to bring it back by dragging it the same distance I made it go out of the screen. Can I put a restriction of some sort on the screen so the mouse doesn't go out of the screen? It's really annoying, I think this OS is thinking that my screen is way bigger than it actually is.

Comment: Sounds like it's detecting a second monitor. Do you have dual screens or anything that would make your computer think there are two screens? (Two cables plugged into video card, software settings, etc..)

Comment: nope. i just did a fresh install. dualboot, win 7. i was thiking, it could detect a second screen, but then, it doesn't go further than say 1.5 inches out of screen. this is only happening with kde as this was not a problem with mint's xfce or cinnamon versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. i figured out the problem. posting it for people who come across the same problem.
somehow, naviage to the display options of your distro. then disable VGA, which is enabled in the distros (known to me): kubuntu 13.04 and linux mint kde 16. this will fix the issue.